# spark taking too much time to load data from cassandra database

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, sparkcore

My Cassandra database has timeseries data stored stored for different `tags`(there are 100 tags) for every `machine` (and 1000 machines in total) for every ten minute `timestamp`. I want to perform analytics on particular days data using `Spark`. Database contains data from past two years that's a huge amount of data.

```
CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(sc)
                  .cassandraTable(database,table)
                  .filter(t->todays(t))
                  .filter(f->f.getString("tag").contains("Temp"))
                  .distinct()
                  .count();
```

this is my code `todays()` fuction filters data based on todays date. Above code is taking lot of time (it has never produced a result actually) where am i doing wrong. Is there any better way to get this data.

This is my table schema,

```
machine_id text,
tag text,
timestamp timestamp,
value double,
PRIMARY KEY (( machine_id, tag ), timestamp)
```

Comment: Without the table schema it's hard to know if you can do better

Comment: thanks for the early reply. I added the schema, can you help me with that now??

Comment: Do you have any exception when doing your request? Can you take a look at your logs to see if everything is working fine?

Comment: With this layout I think every request is necessarily a Full Table Scan. You need to read every partition key to determine whether or not it contains the necessary tag. The composite key means you can't push anything to Cassandra so you'll end up reading entire partitions that are not relevant.

Comment: @M.Situation there are no errors every thing is working fine. only issue is it is taking time